# Select box height issue in iphone while using bootstrap

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, selectboxit

I've a problem in select box in Iphone. Because there is a lot of white space. I need to reduce the height and if I change the height it will change in other mobile browser too, so I need the solution for Iphone only.

Answer (score 0):

@media queries of Css can Be Implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Rohan Kumar Shrestha

But if i use media queries for mobile site then it will change in all mobile devices and in Android phone it is working fine. The problem is with I-phone only.